# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)

Tags: haskell

I am getting following error can any one explain me what is wrong with the code.

```
105:0: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

This is the code:

```
-- Type inference for expressions
--
tyInf :: Gamma -> Exp -> TC (Exp, Type, Subst)
tyInf g (Num n) =  return (Num n, intTyCon, [([intId], intTyCon)])
tyInf g (Con tag[])   
  | tag == unitTag  = return (Con tag[],unitTyCon,[([unitId], unitTyCon)])
  | tag == falseTag = return (Con tag[], boolTyCon, [([boolId],boolTyCon)])
  | tag == trueTag  = return (Con tag[],boolTyCon, [([boolId],boolTyCon)])
  | otherwise       = error "unknown constructor"

tyInf g (Con tag [ e1, e2]) | tag == pairTag = do       
  return ( (Con tag [ e1, e1], (mkPairTy (tyInf g e1) (tyInf g e2)), 
    [([pairId], (mkPairTy (tyInf g e1) (tyInf g e2)))])

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The type for a unifier. A value of this type maps free
-- type variables to real types.
--
-- You may change this type if you wish. The following is
-- one possible type, though not necessarily the best.
--
type Subst = [([TyVar], Type)] -- <--- This is line 105

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Unification
--
unify :: Type -> Type -> Subst
unify t1 t2 
  | t1 == t2  =  []
  | otherwise  =  [(tyVarsIn t1, t2)]
```

Comment: Well, did you check whether that line was indented correctly?

Answer (score 2):

A quick copy and paste of the line of code prior to 105 into an editor that does syntax hilighting shows your parans do not add up.  Try this:

```
 return ( (Con tag [ e1, e1], (mkPairTy (tyInf g e1) (tyInf g e2)),
      [([pairId], (mkPairTy (tyInf g e1) (tyInf g e2)))]))
```

Note the extra `)` at the end.

You really should invest some time into setting up your development environment.  It pays off.